# Netlify redirection doesnt update my path

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom, netlify

Whenever I refresh a page on my deployed netlify site I'm being redirected (as planned) to the main page.

**But the url path itself doesnt change.**

Is it something I need to set in the .toml file or its something with my react routes?

### I'm using:

- `<BrowserRouter/>` of **react-router-dom** to be my router.
- **netlify.toml file**

***netlify.toml:***

```
[[redirects]]
from = "/*"
to = "/index.html"
status = 200
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is [documented](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#http-status-codes) to `rewrite the path`. This is the behavior you may want to see for [history pushstate](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#history-pushstate-and-single-page-apps) in a single page app using react on Netlify so no matter what url path is in the browser request, it will not give a `404`.

If you want to redirect your path you would use a valid `300` status code (301, 302 or 303) like so:

```
[[redirects]]
from = "/home"
to = "/"
status = 301
```